# How do pages like Yahoo Finance update page without plugins etc? (HTTP PUSH)

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, push, yahoo-finance

I am interested in HTTP PUSH technologies. I am interested in the technology behind pages like Yahoo Finance etc, which are able to update the page with data in real time.

When I checked the FF console, there are no periodic POSTs from the client which suggests that the client is not polling, rather it is having data PUSHed to it.

I then checked the page source - (AFAICT) they are NOT:

- using a java applet
- using a hidden iframe
- using any custom client side JS library (like APE etc)

So HOW are the pages being updated in real time?.

Can anyone explain the technolgies used to put together such a page - a link to a simple demo would be most useful.

Answer (score 1):

The techniques for HTTP PUSH and the like are

- [Comet Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)
- [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)
- Java Applet / Flash WebSockets / SilverLight?
- [Server-sent Events and EventSource](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/)
- [HTTP server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push)

The [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) article on wikipedia is a good read.

The [Transports at socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tree/master/lib/transports) should give you examples of how to implement these technologies.

Comment: I am aware of those technologies. My point is that some pages (like the Yahoo finance page I mentioned) do not APPEAR to be using any of these technologies. APE (which I mentioned in my question), is based on Comet. I know (think?) that the Yahoo finance page is not using WebSockets, because the page works in old browsers which don't support HTML5/WebSockets.

Comment: @pinkmonkey4eva last time I checked yahoo finance it used a hidden iframe.