# how to run jsp file continuously without refreshing the page

Tags: jsp, servlets, scheduler

how to run jsp file continuously without refreshing the page and showing updates automatically from my database on that page.

Using this meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15"
the whole browser will refreshed.
Please give me your suggestion

Comment: Don't quite get the question : you do not want to refresh the page manually or you want to avoid the refreshing at all ? Because if refreshing mecanisms are off table, you may want to think about ajax (partial page update).

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to do an ajax call. For example, by using http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I am making a ICU hospital management system  where in as soon as the patient vital parametres are dynmically update on the database, the doctors get the patient_positionin the database.

Comment: To be honest it is a bit scary you are making hospital software and just asking for sample code to copy, instead of reading the links provided that explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all page submitting then you should make an async call and change manually a portion of your page. As this is done directly in the client it means that you have to use an async javascript code: *Ajax*.

So you could invoque periodically a server-side service (soap or rest) to get the 'patient' data. After you read enough ajax and javascript tutorials you could find this link to be useful

[How do server-client push/pull connections work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759247/how-do-server-client-push-pull-connections-work)